# Why CLSLog messages are missing in Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I have an app logging its crashes to Fabric's Crashlytics platform.

The crash logging works as expected, as it can be observed through the platform's dashboard. However, calls to the command `CLSLog` doesn't seem to work as expected. The crashing session's log panel doesn't show a proper log output.

[image: crashlytics session detail log]

This is how we use `CLSLog` within the app:

`CLSLogv(message, getVaList([""]))`

Can somebody point out what might be the possible cause for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution might be somewhat unconventional but what we did in our App was implement crashlytics logging in Objective-C as I recall we had similar issues.

We ended up defining a custom log function that would then use `CLSLog` instead. The benefit is that you don't leak Crashlytics all through your codebase so if you ever want to add other loggers or use a new framework you are safe.

To illustrate we would have:

```
- (void)logMessage:(NSString *)message {
    CLSLog(@"%@", message);
}
```

You can then define a Swift logger that will just use the objective-c function to call.

Our implementation relied on cocoa-lumberjack as we have multiple loggers and such but you should get the idea and hopefully have fun writing ye ol' Objective-C again

Comment: I ended up wrapping all calls to CLSLog in one module and making sure that Fabric's script is being run in the module's build phase. Having done this, I can confirm that the logs can now be registered properly in Crashlytics. I'm not using Objective-C, but your answer is the closest that I got to my final solution, so I'm awarding the bounty to you. Thanks!

Comment: Thats fascinating @Andree but I wonder what the real problem was then?

Answer (score 4):

Seems like there is some mistake in your `CLSLogv` format. please try something like below

```
CLSLogv("%@", getVaList([message]))
```

because of as per fabric custom log [doc](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-logging-in-swift)

> Swift string interpolation will not result in a compile-time constant
>   string. Just like with printf and NSLog, using a non-constant string
>   with CLSLog can result in a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Fabric here. If an empty or nil value is logged, then no log record is displayed. Did you truncate what you're actually logging when posting?

Comment: Hi Mike, I already checked that my log message is not empty or nil. I also have to mention that I have multiple build modules within my app: the app's build target, a share extension target, and some reusable core modules. Do you think `CLSLogv` works in this kind of setup?

Comment: Would need to ensure that Crashlytics has been initialized before logging but in that case, you'd likely get a different error.